# django-rest with multiple url parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using djange-rest framework along with Django 3.0

In my urls.py i have these lines:

```
router.register('search/(?P<param_1>\d+)', SomeView, basename='someview1')
router.register('search/(?P<param_1>\d+)/(?P<param_2>\d+)', SomeView, basename='someview2')
```

I have a problem accessing the second url parameter in the second line. It seems like the first line changes the parsing of the second param of the second line.

In the SomeView class the self.kwargs dictionary has 'param_1' and 'pk'.

If I remove the first line, it all goes well, i get the dictionary populated with 'param_1' and 'param_2'. Is it a weird behavior, or am I missing something?

How do I get 'param_2' in the dictionary in this case?

Comment: You should define different `basename`

Comment: @MuhammadHassan in the working case it's different. I updated the question. That's not the issue

Comment: Does `SomeView(Set)` have a detail view?  If so, since you are matching `\d+`, it might interpret the PK the same way it sees `param_2`, and so always match the first one

Comment: Additionally, use raw strings like `r"search/"` when using regexes, since \d isn't a valid escape seqeuence.  It seems to work, but may be messing things up too.